# Force flexible container to fill all space

Tags: flutter, dart, responsive-design

How can I force my widget (2) to fill the entire screen space and almost hide my widget (1), when keyboard is open ? Example of desired result is under **Desired behavior** picture, I achieved this by changing the widget (2) flex parameter to 9, but I want this to happen automatically...

```
class RegistrationForm extends StatelessWidget {
  const RegistrationForm({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.green,
        child: Form(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Flexible(
                flex: 1,
                child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 60,
                    left: 30,
                    right: 30,
                    bottom: 5,
                  ),
                  height: 240,
                  child: const Text(
                    "Welcome, please fill your data",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Flexible(
                flex: 3,
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 35.0,
                      vertical: 50,
                    ),
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(40),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(40),
                        )),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                      children: [
                        const Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                          child: TextField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Name"),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                          child: TextField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Email"),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                          child: TextField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Password"),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                          child: TextField(
                            decoration:
                                InputDecoration(labelText: "Repeat password"),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 40),
                          child: ElevatedButton(
                            child: Text(
                              "Register",
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
                            ),
                            onPressed: () => print("register"),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### **Default behavior without keyboard:**

[image]

### **Current behavior:**

[image]

### **Desired behavior**:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can detect whether the keyboard is open or closed . Then, if the keyboard is open, you can increase the height of widget 2 and hide widget 1

To detect keyboard visibility, you can use this dependency: [flutter_keyboard_visibility](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_keyboard_visibility)

For your further reference :

[Detect Keyboard is Open or Closed and Its Height](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flutter-detect-keyboard-is-open-or-closed-and-its-height/)

Comment: Thank you, it works, but I wish there will be different approach without using a third party library

Answer (score 0):

remove all the `Flexible` widgets and wrap your column with `SingleChildScrollView`

try this structure:

```
class RegistrationForm extends StatelessWidget {
  const RegistrationForm({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.green,
        child: Form(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              
               Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 60,
                    left: 30,
                    right: 30,
                    bottom: 5,
                  ),
                  height: 240,
                  child: const Text(
                    "Welcome, please fill your data",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35),
      
                ),
              ),
               Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 35.0,
                      vertical: 50,
                    ),
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(40),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(40),
                        )),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                      children: [
                        const Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                          child: TextField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Name"),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                          child: TextField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Email"),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                          child: TextField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Password"),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                          child: TextField(
                            decoration:
                                InputDecoration(labelText: "Repeat password"),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 40),
                          child: ElevatedButton(
                            child: Text(
                              "Register",
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                            onPressed: () => print("register"),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                
            ],
          ),)
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, it's not what I wanted, it's just adding scroll to the screen and when keyboard is open I can scroll the screen, but I want it slides automatically and scroll only my container with input fields ...